# From Whence do we derive that Jews must span the political spectrum?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is there any source for Am Yisrael spanning the gamut of the political spectrum, seeing as we have produced political leaders Left, Right, and Centre.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This explains why even Mordechai was only [רצוי לרוב אחיו](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3310.htm) and not לכל אחיו.

Answer (score 20):

We read in Lecha Dodi "ימין ושמאל תפרוצי", "[To] Right and Left shall you spread [out]". Thus, we derive that we must produce politicians within all facets of the spectrum.

Comment: Oh, I always read that as permission to overeat and not exercise. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Jews are spread over the political spectrum because of their propensity to argue. Many a Jew will take on a political position, often quite forcefully, merely because the person s/he is talking to holds the opposite opinion. They inherit this from their forefather Abraham who said: (Gen. 13:9)

> אִם-הַשְּׂמֹאל וְאֵימִנָה, וְאִם-הַיָּמִין וְאַשְׂמְאִילָה
>
> *If you are to the left, I will be to the right; if you are to the right, I will be to the left.*

Because of this, many Jews argue many different positions, making them span the space of political ideologies.

Answer (score 11):

from the posuk in the shma בְּכָל-לְבָבְךָ וּבְכָל-נַפְשְׁךָ, וּבְכָל-מְאֹדֶךָ

levavcha is the emotional -- the liberal/left
lafshecha -- with guns protecting your life ie the conservative right (alternately, your spiritual side, the Conservative Republican side)
me'odecha -- the Targum translates me'odecha as "moderate" and Rashi connects it to "middle" via the Old French.

The gemara asks "why does it say Uvechol and why not just list the three [aspects]?" It answers "this is to include the extremes". The question is raised. "הכל וכל ובכל מאי?" to include all, simply say "and all" why say "and IN all"? The answer is "this includes the Independent thinkers and Libertarians.

Comment: It seems that this triad could be mapped to various popular axes of political debate. For example, "levavecha" - "your hearts," in plural - represents contemplation of multiple options, i.e. pro-choice, "nafshecha" - "your life" - represents pro-life, and me'odecha, as you showed, represents the middle.